# How to convert the numeric keypad dot-key into the DecimalSeparator?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

In some applications, like *Microsoft Excel*, the dot-key from the numeric keypad (`VK_DECIMAL`) is automatically converted into the current `DecimalSeparator`.

[image: Picture of a numeric keypad with an arrow pointing to the dot key]

I'm trying to implement the same feature but I didn't find a way to make it work in the whole application.

Answer (score -1):

At the form level, it can be done by using the form's [`KeyPreview`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.KeyPreview) property and [`OnKeyPress`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.OnKeyPress) event handler, for example:

```
function IsKeyPressed(const AKey : Word) : Boolean;
begin
  Result := GetKeyState(AKey) < 0;
end;

procedure TMyBaseForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  KeyPreview := True;
end;

procedure TMyBaseForm.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  inherited;
  if(IsKeyPressed(VK_DECIMAL))
  then Key := FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator;
end;
```

But this solution requires to have a common base form class for all application's forms and **won't work with any form/dialog who is not inheriting from that base class** (i.e: It will not work with a simple `InputQuery` either)

Comment: To make it work in all forms, drop a `TApplicationEvents` on your main form and add an `OnMessage` handler. Look for `WM_CHAR` and then replace the `Msg.wParam` accordingly.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: How can I distinguish between `VK_DECIMAL` and `VK_OEM_PERIOD`? The `wParam` is `46` in both cases

Comment: The ugly solution is to continue to use your `IsKeyPressed(VK_DECIMAL)` approach. I haven't had time to investigate the alternatives.

Comment: Remember to also check for the NumLock state. Otherwise someone might expect "Del" key action when pressing that button, and be confused that a decimal point arrives instead.

Comment: `OnKeyPress`/`WM_CHAR` deal in *translated characters*, not in *virtual keys*. To process virtual keys, you need to handle `OnKey(Down|Up)`/`WM_KEY(DOWN|UP)` instead

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand The "ugly solution" works. I've tried extracting the "scan code" from the `WM_CHAR`'s `lParam` and it is 46 (numeric keypad key) and 190. But as far as I know, these values could be hardware dependent, and I didn't find the way to transform them in more reliable values (like virtual keys)

Comment: PS: I don't want to accept my own answer, so, if someone want to post a better one I would be glad to try it and accept it.

Comment: As Remy suggested, handling `WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP` allows to work with virtual keys and distinguish between `VK_DECIMAL` and `VK_OEM_PERIOD` (i.e: `if(Msg.wParam = VK_DECIMAL) then ...`)